# The set of matrices is a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

First problem:
I have set of matrices
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
ry & x 
\end{pmatrix}
where, $x,y \in R$, $R$ is a ring, and $r$ is a fixed element from $R$. I need to proof that this set is a ring with respect to matrix multiplication and addition.

My attempt:

1. I need to show that it is an abelian group with respect to addition.

1.1) Associativity is quite simple

1.2)I need to determine the Identity element. The identity element here is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
ry & x 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
e & e \\
re & e 
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
ry & x 
\end{pmatrix} $$

where $e$ is identity element from $R$

1.3) Need to determine the inverse element

$$\begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
ry & x 
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
-x & -y \\
r(e-y) & -x 
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
e & e \\
re & e 
\end{pmatrix}$$
1.4) the group with respect to + is abelian

2. To proof that multiplication is distributive with respect to addition we need just doing matrix multiplication, nothing special here.

Am I missing something in the first case?

Second problem:
I have another set of matrices:
$$\frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
x & y \\
ay & x 
\end{pmatrix}$$

where $a \in Z$ and not divisible by square of prime, and $x,y \in Z$ have the same parity. How these conditions effect the proof? I don't see any differences with proof if $x,y,a \in Z$.

Comment: Did you check that sums and products of matrices of the form $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} x&y\\ry&x\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ are again of this form?

Comment: @Christoph yes, this is the second part, and it is very long to write it here, I wonder did I make mistake when I determine this set as an abelian group?

Answer (score 1):

Your first proof seems to be correct (You could add that is clossed under addition and multiplication).

For the second problem, you have that:
$$\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
x & y\\
ay & x
\end{pmatrix}\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
x' & y'\\
ay' & x'
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{xx'+ayy'}{2} & \frac{xy'+yx'}{2}\\
a\frac{xy'+yx'}{2} & \frac{xx'+ayy'}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

You must check that $\frac{xx'+ayy'}{2}\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\frac{xy'+yx'}{2}\in \mathbb{Z}$, so for that, you need to use that $a$ is not divisible by square of prime, and $x$, $y$ have the same parity.